# Intellij IDEA generate update method from another object instance. (update RealmObject)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio, code-generation, realm

I have a normal POJO like the following:

```
public class Car extends RealmObject{

    private String name;
    private int maxSpeed;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getMaxSpeed() {
        return maxSpeed;
    }

    public void setMaxSpeed(int maxSpeed) {
        this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to generate an update/copy method that receives another instance of Car? Something like this:

```
public void update(Car other){
    setName(other.getName());
    setMaxSpeed(other.getMaxSpeed());
}
```

I receive a car in JSON format from a server and I use GSON to get a Car instance. If I want to save the car in a Realm I have to do something like this:

```
Car receivedCar = getCarFromServer();
Car car = realm.createObject(Car.class);
car.setName(receivedCar.getName());
car.setMaxSpeed(receivedCar.getMaxSpeed());
```

Note that because of Realm I can't use a copy constructor.

My real models have over 25 fields so it will be a killer job. I would rather generate an update method and do something like this:

```
Car receivedCar = getCarFromServer();
Car car = realm.createObject(Car.class);
car.update(receivedCar);
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can make my job easier?

Comment: You should look at the [Dozer library](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/). It'll do this for you.

Comment: I don't need to copy all fields. Some of them should not be altered, like RealmList. I merged what Christian suggested in his answer. Still, @EngineerDollery if you know a plugin to generate that piece of code I bet it will be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian from Realm here. We are currently looking into how to make an easy to use JSON API. Our current work in progress can be found in this pull request: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/489. Which basically does what you want as a 1-liner.

It is not in the main repository yet, so until  then you either have to build Realm manually or create a copy method like the one you described. Feedback is very welcome though.

Comment: This pull request will be extremely helpful. Any idea on timeline for this PR?

Comment: That was fast! I have the same question as KentAndersen, when will it be available?

Comment: I don't have any timeframe except as soon as possible, sorry.

Comment: I have forked the repo and merged the pull request. Thanks!

Comment: Great, if you find anything that you think could be made easier let us know. We want to make the API as easy to use as possible.